# Malformed url on SEND mediator

Tags: url, wso2-esb

Scenario:
I'm using the WSO2 EI 6.4.0. ESB to convert an incoming SOAP message to JSON and sending it out to our internal applications REST service.

Currently I'm using an inbound endpoint to handle the SOAP request (although I've tried Proxy service which gives me the same result). The incoming message is successfully received, the conversion seems fine as well, but the call to the internal rest is failing. For some reason, the ESB handles all the requests to this rest interface as follows:

```
/http:/InternalApp:8000/rest/xml_messages/iend_incoming
```

Notice that the actual URL that I provide in the SEND mediator is as follows:

```
http://InternalApp:8000/rest/xml_messages/
```

The last piece of the incorrect url (i.e. iend_incoming) is actually the name of the inbound endpoint on the ESB itself. I'm pretty confused as to how this ended up but it looks as though the ESB is considering this to be some sort of proxy call.

The following code is used on the ESB in the sequence tied to aforementioned inbound endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="seq_send_soap_to_rest" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
    <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
            {
           "xml_content": "$1", 
           "sender": "$2",
           "receiver": "$3"
            } 
         </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="base64Encode($env)"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//cac:ConsigneeParty/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//cac:ConsignorParty/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('USRNAME:PWD'))" name="Proxy-Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address format="rest" uri="http://InternalApp:8000/rest/xml_messages/"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Does anyone have any clue as to how that malformed URL ended up there and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was this line:

```
<property name="POST_TO_URI" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
```

Setting it to false gave me a bad request but at least I knew where to look. The name of the variable might be a bit misleading.